# How can I continue running tests in TestNG if one of the test fails

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng

How can I continue running tests in TestNG if one of the test fails. I have followed setting up the configuration policy as continue in the xml file. Below is my xml file. I have also tried setting up each test as (alwaysrun="true"). if one of the test fails then all the other tests are not executed. It displays as failed.

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Regression" verbose="1" configfailurepolicy="continue">


    <!-- yellowfin login credentials -->
    <parameter name="URL" value="http://10.10.5.77:8082/" />
    <parameter name="userName" value="admin" />
    <parameter name="passsword" value="test" />

    <test name="ReportFormatting">
        <classes>
            <class name="fin.bi.test.ReportFormatting">
                <methods>

                    <include name="ValidateDataSection"></include>
                    <include name="ValidateColumnandRowHeadingsandBorder"></include>
                    <include name="ValidateTitleandDescription"></include>
                    <include name="ValidateHeaderFooterandTableSort"></include>
                    <!-- <include name=""></include> -->

                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Here are my tests from my main class. Here I have set "always run" to true. I have searched in stackoverflow and else where and none of them seem to be working. Please advice. Thanks

```
@Parameters({ "userName", "passsword", "viewName", "rf1", "rf2", "rf3", "rf4", "rf5", "fontType" ,"fontSize"})
@Test(testName = "validateDataSection", enabled = true, groups = {"Report Formatting : Data"}, alwaysRun = true, priority=1)
public void ValidateDataSection(String username, String password, String viewName, String r1, String r2, String r3, String r4, String r5, String ftype, String fsize) throws InterruptedException, AWTException {
    extentTest = extent.startTest("ValidateDataSection");

    login.loginToTenant(username, password);
    // select view from content menu button
    createContentMenuButton.setContentMenuButton();
    // choose view
    reportView.selectView(viewName);
    // create the report in report builder
    createChart.createReport(r1, r2, r3, r4, r5);

    //Checks the style "Font Type, Font Size, Bold Italic"
    reportFormattingPage.DataSection(ftype,fsize);

    // Access Row Highlight
    reportFormattingPage.RowHighlight();

    logout.performLogout();


}


@Parameters({ "userName", "passsword", "viewName", "rf1", "rf2", "rf3", "rf4", "rf5", "headerFontType", "headerFontSize", "borderWidth"})
@Test(testName = "Validate Column & Row Headings and Border", enabled = true, groups = {"Report Formatting : Column & Row Headings and Border"}, alwaysRun = true, priority=1)
public void ValidateColumnandRowHeadingsandBorder(String username, String password, String viewName, String r1, String r2, String r3,   String r4, String r5, String headerFontType, String headerFontSize, String borderWidth) throws InterruptedException {
    extentTest = extent.startTest("ValidateColumnandRowHeadingsandBorder");

    login.loginToTenant(username, password);
    // select view from content menu button
    createContentMenuButton.setContentMenuButton();
    // choose view
    reportView.selectView(viewName);
    // create the report in report builder
    createChart.createReport(r1, r2, r3, r4, r5);

    // validates the column and Row headings
    reportFormattingPage.ColumnAndRowHandling(headerFontType, headerFontSize);

    // Validates the border
    reportFormattingPage.Border(borderWidth);

    logout.performLogout();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the documentation :

`configfailurepolicy` - Whether to continue attempting Before/After Class/Methods after they've failed once or just skip remaining. So this has no effect on regular test methods and affects only configuration methods.

`alwaysRun` - If set to true, this test method will always be run even if it depends on a method that failed.  This attribute will be ignored if this test doesn't depend on any method or group. In your sample you don't seem to be having any dependencies between methods. So this attribute is also going to be ignored.

What you have shared is a very basic use case for TestNG.

Here's a simple example that shows this functionality in action (I am working with TestNG version `6.14.3`)

Here's my sample test class

```java
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class SampleTestClass {
    @Test(groups = {"Report Formatting : Data"})
    public void testMethodA() {
        throw new RuntimeException("Intentionally failing the test");
    }

    @Test(groups = {"Report Formatting : Column & Row Headings and Border"})
    public void testMethodB() {
        System.err.println("testMethodB()");
    }
}
```

Here's how my suite xml looks like :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="49483424_Suite" parallel="false" verbose="2" >
    <test name="49483424_test" verbose="2">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn49483424.SampleTestClass">
                <methods>
                    <include name="testMethodA"/>
                    <include name="testMethodB"/>
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

And here's the complete execution output

```
...
... TestNG 6.14.3 by Cédric Beust (cedric@beust.com)
...

java.lang.RuntimeException: Intentionally failing the test

    at com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn49483424.SampleTestClass.testMethodA(SampleTestClass.java:8)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)

testMethodB()
PASSED: testMethodB
FAILED: testMethodA
java.lang.RuntimeException: Intentionally failing the test
    at com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn49483424.SampleTestClass.testMethodA(SampleTestClass.java:8)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:583)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:719)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:989)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:72)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:123)


===============================================
    49483424_test
    Tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

===============================================
49483424_Suite
Total tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


Process finished with exit code 0
```

So I would suggest that you please first try running a simple test excluding all of the other dependencies such as extent reports etc., and check to make sure if it works fine for you in a plain Java test.
If it still doesn't work, then I request you to please file a bug here : https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues and include a sample test (preferably one which does not have any dependency on any external library but just makes use of a bunch of print statements to show the bug) in it. I will take a look to see what is going wrong.